# How to sum single value from Header and Total value from detail using mysql left join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two table with one to many relationship. One is header and the other is detail.

Header Table Columns are State, Item, Bill, Quantity

Detail Table Columns are Header_ID, Allocated To, Allocated Quantity

I need to get the sum of Header Quantity and Sum of Detail Quantity using left join as detail may not exists sometime.

Here is how it looks after joining (Before grouping)

[image]

My required result after grouping should be

```
State, Item, Total Quantity (Header), Total Allocated (Detail Quantity).
```

But my problem is i am doing left join so header value is repeating, when i sum the duplicate values are also summing up.

Here is the Query i tried

```
SELECT
  a.State,
  a.Item,
  b.Allocated,
  sum(a.Quantity) AS Header_Total, -- Should take unique/single
  sum(b.Quantity) AS Detail_Taol
FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.Header_ID
GROUP BY
  a.State,
  a.Item,
  b.Allocated;
```

Please help in querying this to get the desired result.

Comment: add the sql that you have tried.

Comment: Info about "Help others reproduce the problem" is missing, see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Share some table definitions, some data, end desired output.

Comment: Your two tables do not seem to have any column in common. How do you relate them?

Comment: The picture indicates the result comes after joining. Have edited the question and added query which i am using to get the result

Comment: There are columns in the query which are absent in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN (including LEFT JOIN) creates a result set containing all pairs of rows allowed by the ON clause.  So your SUM(a,Quantity) expression adds up multiple copies of that value and so generates wrong results in a lot of cases.

This is sometimes called a combinatorial explosion or a cardinality error.

Fix: take off the SUM and add a.Quantity to the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
  a.State,
  a.Item,
  b.Allocated,
  a.Quantity AS Header_Total, 
  sum(b.Quantity) AS Detail_Taol
FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.Header_ID
GROUP BY
  a.State,
  a.Item,
  b.Allocated,
  a.Quantity;
```